# Product identification/recommendation to seal top of foundation wall

Tags: foundation, waterproofing, exterior, sealant

In preparation for winter, I've started to inspect the exterior of my house and noticed some of the sealant at the top of the basement wall needs replacing. Unfortunately I bought the house like this so I don't know what the previous owner did. I live in Toronto, which has humidity from 0 - 60 RH, and a temperature range of around -35ºC to +35ºC. The wall is Insulbrick and the foundation is covered with a cement render.  Snow will regularly settle on this surface during winter.

Three questions here:
 1. What is this product?
 2. Any tips for repair and replacement?
 3. This is about 10 years old. Are there better products on the market now?

Here is what I am trying to replace:
[image: Failing sealant on exterior of house wall at top of foundation wall]

And here is me trying to picture where this is better!
[image]